# Very weird behaviour while copying matrix in constructor

Tags: java, matrix, constructor, deep-copy

I'm making a class which stores a 9x9 int matrix representing a sudoku in:

```
private final int sudoku[][];
```

I'm making a constructor which takes in a matrix and copies that into the variable that I declared before:

```
public SudokuMatrix(int[][] sudoku)
{
    this.sudoku= new int[9][];

    if (sudoku.length != 9 || sudoku[0].length != 9) 
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong dimension!");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
        {
            this.sudoku[i] = sudoku[i].clone();
        }

    }
}
```

It should be no big deal, but when I try to use it with a matrix like this:

```
int[][] init = new int[][]{
            {0, 0, 5, 0, 2, 1, 7, 0, 0},
            {0, 9, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 6, 0},
            {8, 0, 0, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4},
            {7, 0, 0, 1, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0},
            {0, 2, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            {0, 0, 1, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0, 7},
            {6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 9},
            {0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 7, 0},
            {0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0},
    };
SudokuMatrix s = new SudokuMatrix(init);
```

When I print the matrix contained inside s, the function I'm using to print it (which I'm sure is correct) should print something like:

```
|..5|.21|7..|
|.9.|.7.|.6.|
|8..|35.|..4|
|---+---+---|
|7..|18.|3..|
|.2.|.9.|.1.|
|..1|26.|..7|
|---+---+---|
|6..|..2|..9|
|.3.|.4.|.7.|
|..4|5..|8..|
```

('.' is an empty space in the sudoku, represented by the 0 value)

Instead, I get this awful thing:

```
|..♣|.☻☺|..|
|.      .|..|.♠.|
..|♥♣.|..♦|
|---+---+---|
|...|♥..|
|.☻.|.  .|.☺.|
|..☺|☻♠.|..|
|---+---+---|
|♠..|..☻|..     |
|.♥.|.♦.|..|
|..♦|♣....|
```

I really can't figure out where can I do wrong, copying a matrix into another is something which I've never got problems with, so has it something to do with the fact that I'm in a constructor?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

**Edit: Printing code**
This is the method I use to turn the sudoku into a string, I then print it:

```
public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder sdk = new StringBuilder("");
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
    {
        sdk.append("|");
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) 
        {
            if (this.griglia[i][j] == 0) 
                {
                    sdk.append(".");
                }
            else sdk.append((char) this.griglia[i][j]);

            if ((j+1)%3 == 0) 
            {
                sdk.append("|");
            }
        }
        if((i+1)%3 == 0)
        {
            sdk.append("\n");
            sdk.append("|---+---+---|");
        }
        sdk.append("\n");
    }

    return sdk.toString();
}
```

Comment: Are you printing your output to the console? Also can you post your print method.

Comment: Yes, I am. But I am also comparing it to the one that I should actually get (using a dedicated method) and they don't match.

Comment: Do you use something like BufferedReader in your print method?

Comment: Edited, there's now the printing method.

Comment: Just eliminate the cast to char.

Comment: ...yeah, I just figured it out by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you cast the int into a char (char) this.griglia[i][j], it casts it to some weird ascii character. Try the below code to simplify your solution. Or change it to else{sdk.append( "" + this.griglia[i][j])}

Maybe I would try the following:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int[][] init = new int[][]{
            {0, 0, 5, 0, 2, 1, 7, 0, 0},
            {0, 9, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 6, 0},
            {8, 0, 0, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4},
            {7, 0, 0, 1, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0},
            {0, 2, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            {0, 0, 1, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0, 7},
            {6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 9},
            {0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 7, 0},
            {0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0},
    };
    SudokuMatrix s = new SudokuMatrix(init);

    s.printMatrix();
  }
}

public class SudokuMatrix
{
  private final int sudoku[][];



  public SudokuMatrix(int[][] sudoku){
    this.sudoku= new int[9][9]; //note here I allocated a 9x9 matrix rather than copying each row in the matrix

    if (sudoku.length != 9 || sudoku[0].length != 9) 
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong dimension!");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
               this.sudoku[i][j] = sudoku[i][j];
            }

        }

    }
}

  public void printMatrix(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){

      String inner = "";
      for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
        if(sudoku[i][j] == 0){
              inner += ".";
        }
        else{inner += sudoku[i][j];}
    }
      System.out.println(inner);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: I already tried the "double for" way of copying a matrix, but result was the same. Also, I tried to change the SudokuMatrix to public but it doesn't change anything anyway...

Comment: In the end, my code worked fine with just removing the cast to char... thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use clone() as it needs to be overwritten to work properly. Instead try direct copy.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your

```
StringBuilder sdk = new StringBuilder("");
```

with,

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-16LE"));
```